# Stuck in grub rescue

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows, grub2, dual-boot

Ugh.
I installed Ubuntu alongside my win7 install, I deleted my Ubuntu partition to get more C: drive space now I’m stuck in grub rescue. **Also I can’t use a Ubuntu install to boot I have no access to another PC or  a windows installer** *(I have a windows 10 HDD but I have a OEM key for win7)* And  **I have no way of backing up my 600 GB hdd** also I hate win10.
Edit: After I deleted the partition I thought I messed up grub. But I thought “Well I just made that bootable clover USB” but they don’t work on BIOS. Just great.

Comment: You need to use a Windows repair/recovery disk and its repair console. You need to run the fixMBR command to restore a Windows boot loader to MBR and maybe other Windows repairs. You can use a Windows 10 repair disk.

Comment: I said I don’t have a repair disk.

Comment: You said you have Windows 10. So you can make a repair disk.

Comment: But wouldn’t that only work for windows 10 not windows 7?

Comment: why are you asking microsoft windows questions at a Unix/Linux site?

Comment: I’m stuck in grub. And grub is not buy Microsoft. It’s usually used for Linux. I removed Linux now I’m stuck in grub rescue

Comment: See first comment.